# Change default product currency based on a product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to change the Woocommerce's product default currency based on the category.

Like if "Audio" is a category then set the EUR to be the currency.

I've tried the code below but it's not working:

```
function change_woocommerce_currency( $currency ) {
    if ( is_product_category( 'audio' ) ) {
        $currency = 'EUR'; 
    }
    return $currency;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency', 'change_woocommerce_currency' );
```

The currency price needs to be changed on the product page as well that currency to be on the cart and checkout page, and the charge needs to happen in that category's currency.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: did any of the answers worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can create a custom field with [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to store EUR regular prices (For example: regular_price_eur)

Then, you can filter the price and change its currency symbol based on the category.

```
function filter_price( $price, $product ) {
  $price_in_eur = get_field( 'regular_price_eur', $product->get_id() ); // get EUR price from a custom field

  if ( $price_in_eur && is_product_category( 'audio' ) ) {
    return absint( $price_in_eur );
  } else {
    return $price;
  }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'filter_price', 10, 2 );

function change_currency_symbol( $currency ) {
  if ( is_product_category( 'audio' ) )  {
    return 'EUR';
  }

  return $currency;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency', 'change_currency_symbol' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
    function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
        global $post, $product;
    
        if ( has_term( 'audio', 'product_cat' ) ) {
            switch( $currency ) {
                 case 'USD': $currency_symbol = 'EUR'; 
                 break;
            }
        }
        return $currency_symbol; // <== HERE
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_woocommerce_currency( $currency ) {
    $defaultCurrency = 'EUR';
    $categories = [
       'audio'  => 'EUR',
       'mobile' => 'LEK',  
     ];
    $productCategory = 'audio'; // get product's category
    return $categories[$productCategory] ?: $defaultCurrency;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency', 'change_woocommerce_currency' );
```

Answer (score -1):

You have various ways to do that. First, you can use a plugin, such as "WooCommerce Currency per Product", this lets you add a specific currency to any item you want.

If you want to do it by code, this is how i would have done it :

```
function change_woocommerce_currency( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
  if ( is_product_category( 'audio' ) ) {
    switch( $currency ) {
      case 'USD': $currency_symbol = 'whatever you want'; 
      break;
      }
    }
    return $currency_symbol;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency', 'change_woocommerce_currency' );
```

Comment: Site breaks with this one

Comment: I need the function.

Comment: @MarkoI. you can use the below plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/currency-per-product-for-woocommerce/

Comment: @MarkoI. You can try this hook `woocommerce_currency_symbol` as I have posted in answer